# Joining text to the previous line

Tags: text, awk, concatenation

Currently working on Solaris

I need to search for a specific string in a text file and, if found, join it to the previous line. For example:

```
if logical condition
then
i = i + 1
```

Would become

```
if logical condition then
i = i + 1.
```

I'm sure I can do this with awk using a hold space of some sort but my awk skills are a little rusty.

---

Addendum: Apologies, I should have been more specific. The match is triggered by the appearance of the string "then". I have no knowledge of the contents of the previous line - it could be anything. Whatever it is I need to concatenate the "then" to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?(/then/?FS:RS):""), $0} END{print ""}' file
if logical condition then
i = i + 1
```

Comment: This is probably the best. I just quake in fear when I hear Solaris. `:)`

Comment: It'll work fine on Solaris with any of the awks that aren't old, broken awk, i.e. nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. Hopefully the OP already knows that, otherwise we can look forward to the "syntax error on line 1" that old broken awk loves to spit out for just about every awk script!

Comment: @jaypal /You/ quake in fear? Spare a thought for me. Locked down. Can't use anything FOSS, can't use sunfreeware.com. Getting access to anything is by committee. <Sigh>

Comment: @Ed Morton - Thanks Ed - much appreciated. using /usr/xpg4/bin/awk that worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '
  function dump(trailing_line) {
    for (i = 0; i < length(previous) - 1; i++)
      print previous[i]
    if (trailing_line) { 
      print previous[i] trailing_line 
    } else { 
      print previous[i] 
    }
    i = 0
    delete previous
  }
  /then/ {
    dump(" then")
    next
  }
  {
    previous[i++] = $0
  }
  END {
    dump("")
  }
' your_input_file
```

If you truly have no knowledge of what comes before the `then`, you will have to store each line into an array and then dump them out before you emit the `then`.  Since you will also want to do this within the `END` clause, it's easiest to make this "dumping" action into a function.

Comment: This got me half way there. Can you explain how can I add an "else print the line anyway" so I get the full contents of my text file along with the transformed lines?